# How to change JButton size in JPanel which is "spread" at whole JFrame

Tags: java

So I have a problem,because mine JButtons are just too bige, I need to change their size to be for eg small rectangles or squares. Right now they look like piano keys.

This is my paste.Could you guys help? :)
I tried SetSize or SetDimension or all the methods available but it did not work out. And I haven't found relevant topic here at overflow. What do you think?

```
package sg;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SG  extends JFrame {

    JPanel pn1;
    JPanel pn2;
    JPanel pn3;
    JPanel pn4;
    JButton[] buttony = new JButton[12];
    JButton start;

    SG() {

       super();


        setSize(1000, 900);
        setResizable(false);

        pn1 = new JPanel();
        pn2 = new JPanel();

         pn1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
         pn2.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,6));

        start = new JButton("Start");
        start.addActionListener(new B1());
        pn1.add(start);


        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            buttony[i] = new JButton(Integer.toString(i + 1));
            buttony[i].setSize(10, 10);
            pn2.add(buttony[i]);
        }

        add(pn1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(pn2,BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          SG adam = new SG();
         adam.setVisible(true);
    }
   private class B1 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Random s = new Random();
            int a = s.nextInt(5);
            System.out.println(a);
        }

}
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `pn2` to another `JPanel` and then set that panel to the `JFrame` using [setContentPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setContentPane-java.awt.Container-).

The complete code is as follows:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SG extends JFrame {

    JPanel pn1;
    JPanel pn2;
    JPanel pn3;
    JPanel pn4;
    JButton[] buttony = new JButton[12];
    JButton start;

    SG() {

        super();

        setSize(1000, 900);
        setResizable(false);

        pn1 = new JPanel();
        pn2 = new JPanel();
        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();

        pn1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        pn2.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 6));

        start = new JButton("Start");
        start.addActionListener(new B1());
        pn1.add(start);

        for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            buttony[i] = new JButton(Integer.toString(i + 1));
            buttony[i].setSize(10, 10);
            pn2.add(buttony[i]);
        }
        contentPane.add(pn2);
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        add(pn1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(pn2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SG adam = new SG();
        adam.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class B1 implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            Random s = new Random();
            int a = s.nextInt(5);
            System.out.println(a);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to use GridBagLayout, be sure to read this page:
   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html
   which suggests defining constraints before adding elements. 
   My choice is `MigLayout`. Google it and check 5+ versions.
2. The default size of a component, is barely defined by `setSize()`, because layout managers often use it to define the dimensions of each components to resize them, so your effort will almost always be overwritten. If you want, try `setPreferedSize()`, `setMinimumSize()` and `setMaximumSize()`.
3. About the topic of Swing, StackOverFlow has plenty of questions related. Try searching tag `swing`. Also, the Oracle guide is a must-read: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html. And each layout manager has its own documentation. Like Miglayout. http://www.miglayout.com/

Be patient. Several month of time is required to get an rough idea of all this.

Answer (score 0):

GUI components such as `JButton` need to be placed in a container. `JPanel` is a container. Containers have an associated [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/LayoutManager2.html). The layout manager determines the size and location of the components within the container. The `GridLayout` divides the container into a grid of equal sized cells and places exactly one component in each cell. In the code you posted, each cell contains exactly one `JButton`, hence each button has the same size. Explicitly setting the `JButton` size will not help because `GridLayout` ignores it.

Therefore you need to use a layout manager that is appropriate for your needs. You want to lay out your `JButton`s in a grid but have each `JButton` displayed with its preferred size. An appropriate layout manger for this is `GridBagLayout`. It lays out the components in a grid but sizes each component according to its preferred size.

The following code is a rewrite of the code you posted, because I felt that starting from scratch would be more beneficial to you than patching the code you posted. In the below code, I am using `GridBagLayout` to lay out the grid of `JButton`s.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class SG1 implements ActionListener, Runnable {
    private static final int NUMBER_OF_BUTTONS = 12;
    private static final String START = "Start";

    private JButton[] buttons;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textField;

    public SG1() {
        buttons = new JButton[NUMBER_OF_BUTTONS];
    }

    @Override // java.awt.event.ActionListener
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String actionCommand = e.getActionCommand();
        switch (actionCommand) {
            case START:
                Random s = new Random();
                int a = s.nextInt(5);
                textField.setText(String.valueOf(a));
                break;
            default:
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                                              actionCommand,
                                              "Unhandled",
                                              JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    @Override // java.lang.Runnable
    public void run() {
        createAndShowGui();
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("SG1");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(createTextFieldPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        frame.add(createButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createStartButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel createButtonsPanel() {
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.insets.top = 3;
        gbc.insets.right = 3;
        gbc.insets.left = 3;
        gbc.insets.bottom = 3;
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_BUTTONS; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new JButton(String.format("%02d", (i + 1)));
            buttonsPanel.add(buttons[i], gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            if (gbc.gridx > (NUMBER_OF_BUTTONS / 2) - 1) {
                gbc.gridx = 0;
                gbc.gridy++;
            }
        }
        return buttonsPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createStartButtonPanel() {
        JPanel startButtonPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton startButton = new JButton(START);
        System.out.println(startButton.getFont());
        startButton.addActionListener(this);
        startButtonPanel.add(startButton);
        return startButtonPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createTextFieldPanel() {
        JPanel textFieldPanel = new JPanel();
        textField = new JTextField(10);
        textFieldPanel.add(textField);
        return textFieldPanel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new SG1());
    }
}
```

I suggest you thoroughly study the above code and if there are parts you don't understand, then search the Internet for explanations. You will find many examples for each part of it.

For learning *Swing* in general, I recommend the online tutorial [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html). I also recommend the book [Core JFC (2nd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013090581X) by Kim Topley